Outlook already running
This is the new mail client for Windows 11 which MS have decided to call outlook.  It is not about Outlook that comes with office.
When I first start up the mail client, everything works fine.  If I then close it (click on X) and then reopen it about 20 or 30 minutes later, it opens, but I also get a pop up box saying "Outlook is already running".  If doesn't happen if I close it and reopen immediately.


One common cause is twice trying to run a single-instance application that is slow to start. For example, one clicks on an icon or presses the keyboard shortcut, and nothing appears to happen, and then one repeats the action, impatiently. The same thing happens with the Thunderbird email client, as well as Outlook. Some applications have splash screens to notify the user that the app is starting up, albeit s l o w l y.
For ways to determine other causes of that issue, try the following:

Press CtrlShiftEsc to open Task Manager while Outlook is running.
Open the Details tab.
Find Outlook in the list. There may be more than one process, because they're doing different tasks (e.g., fetching messages, showing them on screen, indexing them, etc.).
Now close Outlook completely. After a few seconds or a minute, all Outlook processes should disappear from Task Manager.

If there are any Outlook processes, you've identified the issue. There are a few things to try to fix that issue.

Disable or remove any extensions to Outlook. Test again, and if that fixes the issue, test each extension for being the cause.
If you have third-party antimalware suite (AV), such as Kaspersky, Norton, AVG or Panda), disable it temporarily -- it might keep Outlook open to scan messages. If that is the cause, then check with the AV maker for a fix, or try another AV... or just give it sufficient time to finish scanning.
If indexing prevents Outlook from closing, consider not indexing messages.

After fixing the issue, scan and repair the .PST file that stores emails, because failures to close Outlook gracefully can damage that file.

It is basically because I am double clicking on the email client.  If I single click on the mail client, it starts, if I double click, two copies start.  The first one starts, the second one pops up the error message.

+1 Actually, that is a valid answer, too, and I'll add it to mine.
